# Why can't methods with pointer and non-pointer receivers have the same name in Go?

Tags: pointers, methods, go, types

My understanding is that `Cat` and `*Cat` are different types in Go. So why do their names conflict?

```
type Animal interface {
    GetName() string
    SetName(string) 
}

type Cat struct {
    Name string
}

func (c *Cat) GetName() string {
    return c.Name
}

func (c Cat) GetName() string {
    return c.Name
}

func (c *Cat) SetName(s string) {
    c.Name = s
}
```

Comiler response:

> method redeclared: Cat.GetName

Comment: Either it's a bug or a deliberate part of the implementation because having both versions of the method is just stupid. That's what dereferencing/address of is there for. If you have a pointer or an instance you can get the other quite easily.

Comment: Consider `interface{GetName()string}` which method would get called if you would pass a struct implementing this interface to a function that would take this interface as an argument ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Spec: Method sets:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> The method set of any other type `T` consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is **the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).**

So if you have a method with `Cat` as the receiver type, that method is also part of the method set of `*Cat`. So `*Cat` will already have that method, attempting to declare "another" one with the same name and `*Cat` as the receiver type will be a duplicate.

To verify it, see this example:

```
type Cat struct{ Name string }

func (c Cat) GetName() string { return c.Name }
```

We only declare one method with non-pointer receiver. If we check / print the methods of the corresponding `*Cat` type:

```
func main() {
    var cp *Cat = &Cat{} // Pointer
    t := reflect.TypeOf(cp)
    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(t.Method(i).Name)
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3Wv4JPsfaV)):

```
GetName
```

The type `*Cat` already has a `GetName` method. Adding another one with `*Cat` receiver would collide with the one above.

Related question from the official FAQ: [Why does Go not support overloading of methods and operators?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading)